# how to use an object that is created already as an argument in java

Tags: java, variable-assignment

I have an `AddressBook` class and a `Persons` class in my program. The `AddressBook` class has an array of `Persons` object.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Persons {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String addres;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private int zip;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Persons(String name , String lastname,String phoneNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastname;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

//some getter and setter here for all private fields and some other code
```

and this is the `AddressBook.addPerson` method:

```
public void addPerson(Persons prs) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ArrayOfPerson.length; i++) {
        if (ArrayOfPerson[i] == null) {
            ArrayOfPerson[i] = prs;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and the `Main` class :

```
public class Main {        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AddressBook addr = new AddressBook();
        addr.addPerson(new Persons("first name", "first lastname", "123"));// in here for example/ how can i use this person object later
        addr.addPerson(new Persons("second name", "second lastname", "456"));
        addr.addPerson(new Persons("third name", "thirs last name", "789"));
        addr.addPerson(new Persons("fourth name", "fourth last name", "101112"));
    }
}
```

My question regards the `Main` class. How can I re-use the created persons object? For example, I would want to do something like this :

```
System.out.println(x.getname());
```

where x is a person object that is created by `new` keyword as a argument.

Excuse me if my question is that of a beginner ... I searched in google and found nothing.

Comment: You're constructing `Persons` objects in a sort of "anonymous" way. The object created (from `new`) itself may be accessible through your collection, but in the scope of your `main`, you don't have access to it in the form of a variable. You should instantiate each `Persons` object and set it to a variable, and _then_ add each to the `AddressBook`, using your `.addPerson` method.

Comment: You can either assign it to a variable while you are creating it, or just get it from the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to assign this object to a variable while creating it then you can access it and pass it as parameter :

```
Persons firstOne = new Persons("first name","first lastname","123");
```

And your code will be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AddressBook addr = new AddressBook();
    Persons firstOne = new Persons("first name","first lastname","123");

    //You will use it as parameter like this:
    addr.addPerson(firstOne);
    addr.addPerson(new Persons("second name", "second lastname","456"));
    addr.addPerson(new Persons("third name", "thirs last name","789"));
    addr.addPerson(new Persons("fourth name", "fourth last name","101112"));
}
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
System.out.println(firstOne.getname());
```

Or without creating a variable you can get it from the collection by its index `addr.get(index)` :

```
System.out.println(addr.get(0).getname());
```

Answer (score 2):

You should store store every `Persons` into a variable like this :

```
Persons p1 = new Persons("first name","first lastname","123")
```

Then to get the field `name` :

```
System.out.println(p1.getName());
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to assing the person to a variable:

```
Person x = new Persons("fourth name", "fourth last name","101112"));
```

Then you can do:

```
addr.addPerson(x);
System.out.println(x.getname());
```

or you can take the element from the lits:

```
System.out.println(addr.get(3).getname())
```

Answer (score 2):

You would do something like this:

```
  public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AddressBook addr = new AddressBook();
    addr.addPerson(new Persons("first name","first lastname","123"));// in here for example/ how can i use this person object later
    addr.addPerson(new Persons("second name", "second lastname","456"));
    Person x = new Persons("third name", "thirs last name","789")
    addr.addPerson(x);
    addr.addPerson(new Persons("fourth name", "fourth last name","101112"));
    System.out.println(x.getName());
}
```